# Custom formula in conditional formatting rule sometimes works wrong

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am using the formula `= C2 + B2 <> A2` to highlight the cells where this condition is true. For some reason, this formula does not work correctly in some cells. For example, in cells C1, C17.

[image]

Please understand the reason.
All numbers in columns A through C are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is using relative references, but not the right ones. In row 1 you want to compare the values in row 1, in row 2 values of same row and so on.

In your image you've selected C1 and the rule there should be `= C1 + B1 <> A1`, not `= C2 + B2 <> A2`

C1 is being highlighted because C2 + B2 is not equal to A2. 12115+460=12575, which is different from 12573.

Same for C17. Your conditional formula is looking 1 row below. Try using

`= C1 + B1 <> A1`